# How do I stop/shutdown the native CouchDB app on OSX?

Tags: couchdb

I installed and ran the native app following these instructions:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/mac.html#installation-using-the-apache-couchdb-native-application

How to I now shutdown/kill/stop CouchDB?

Answer (score 6):

I found this

https://www.gregoryvarghese.com/how-to-stop-couchdb-on-mac-os/

In terminal , run

```
launchctl list | grep couchdb
```

then on the retnurned value like

```
99093 0 org.apache.couchdb.288008
```

do

```
launchctl stop "org.apache.couchdb.288008"
```

Has to be a higher level GUI for that in Futon though surely !!

Answer (score 2):

The CouchDB App on Mac OS X seems to use a watcher that restarts the database if the process stops. So first run this command to list all running processes started by the Couch App:

`ps -ef | grep -i couch`

Here's the output I get:

```
  501  4330     1   0 Tue12pm ??         0:06.17 /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/MacOS/Apache CouchDB -psn_0_659617
  501 23991  4330   0  6:31pm ??         0:01.82 /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/bin/../erts-8.3/bin/beam.smp -K true -A 16 -Bd -- -root /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/bin/.. -progname couchdb -- -home /Users/eric -- -boot /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/bin/../releases/2.1.1/couchdb -name couchdb@localhost -setcookie monster -kernel error_logger silent -sasl sasl_error_logger false -noshell -noinput -config /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/bin/../releases/2.1.1/sys.config -couch_ini /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/etc/default.ini /Users/eric/Library/Preferences/couchdb2-local.ini
  501 23999     1   0  6:31pm ??         0:00.00 /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/bin/../erts-8.3/bin/epmd -daemon
  501 24003 24000   0  6:31pm ??         0:00.01 /Applications/Development/Apache CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/bin/../lib/os_mon-2.4.2/priv/bin/cpu_sup
  501 24015 18419   0  6:32pm ttys000    0:00.01 grep Couch
```

The first one seems to be a watcher, and if it notices that other commands have been stopped it will restart Couch.

So kill the first one first `Apache CouchDB` (in my case PID 4330), then the second one (in my case PID 23991), and Couch should no longer be running. Confirm by rerunning the ps command:

`ps -ef | grep -i couch`

Answer (score 1):

It does not work. `ps aux | grep couchdb` shows that couchdb is still running :(

```
$ launchctl list | grep couchdb

-   0   org.apache.couchdb.79668

$ launchctl stop "org.apache.couchdb.79668"
```